# How to change an element's background-image url in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Im using ASP.NET Core 2.2. I don't knwo how to change background url of an element.

This is **HTML** of page

```
 <div>
    <a class="img-holder" href="#"></a>
 </div>
```

And this is **CSS** part

```
.img-holder
{
  background-image: url('myimg.jpg');
}
```

I want to change the background image of *.img-holder* and retrieve the url from my data base.

**I don't want to use img tag.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Razor syntax and MVC, you can populate your viewmodel or ViewBag with the URL of the image. Then you can populate the image in the view using

```
 <div>
    <a href="#" style="background-image: @Url.Content('image-url')"></a>
 </div>
```

By the way, you are also missing closing double quotes for your class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image path is correct.Then use `display` property to show the image and use `height` and `width` to define the image size.For example:

```
<div>
   <a class="img-holder" href="#"></a>
</div>

.img-holder {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: url("myimg.jpg");

    }
```